# How do I get fullcalendar to display calendar on initial render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

When I initially load my calendar, it loads the calendar with all of the headings/buttons, but not the actual calendar itself.  I have to press the "today" button for it to load the calendar on today's week.  Any idea how to get it to do this on initial load?  If it helps, here's the code I'm using.  I'm pretty clueless as to what's happening here, I inherited this piece of work off someone else, this is my first time looking at this fullcalender addon.

```
function calendar() {

    //gets saved events
    var sourceFullView = { url: '/Calendar/GetDiaryEvents/' };
    var sourceSummaryView = { url: '/Calendar/GetDiarySummary/' };
    var CalLoading = true;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        selectable: true,
        slotMinutes: 15,
        events: '/Calendar/GetDiaryEvents/',
        eventClick:
            function(calEvent) {
                //modal located at the bottom of the page
                var modalElementId = $("#modal");
                //url located in the Calendar controller. CalEvent Id referes to event id
                var url = GetUrlPath() + '/Calendar/OpenDetailsModal?id=' + calEvent.id;
                var appointmentId = calEvent.id;
                //These are defined at the top of the page
                $('#DiaryEventID').val(appointmentId);
                $('#DiaryEventID').val("");
                var viewModel = new CalenderViewModel(appointmentId);
                showEditModal(null, viewModel, url, modalElementId);
                $('.modal-backdrop').removeClass('modal-backdrop');
            },

        eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
            if (confirm("Confirm move?")) {
                UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start);
            } else {
                revertFunc();
            }
        },

        eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
            if (confirm("Confirm change appointment length?")) {
                UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start, event.end);
            } else {
                revertFunc();
            }
        },

        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#eventTitle').val("");
            setTimeout(ShowClientEventModal(), 100);
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (date != "") {
                    $('#eventClientDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
                    $('#eventClientTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'HH:mm'));
                    $("#eventClientDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
                }
            }
        },

        viewRender: function(view, element) {

            if (!CalLoading) {
                if (view.name == 'month') {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                } else {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    CalLoading = false;
}
```

Bit more info, this is strange, but when I press F12 on the browser to go into developer tools, then calendar suddenly renders as if I pressed the today button.  But when I go into the calendar page with the debugger already open, it renders the headers without the calendar content.  What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try removing all code related to `CalLoading`, so remove the variable assignment from the top, remove the entire viewRender function, and remove the variable assignment to `false` at the bottom. It looks like some type of function for not displaying the events until they are all loaded, or something like that, and my guess is its not working properly.

Edit: It looks like the function swaps out event sources to `sourceSummaryView` on month view, and `sourceFullView` on any other, so removing this will still have the calendar default to the `sourceFullView`, but I do not know the difference of the two so you will just need to try and see how it works.

```
var CalLoading = true;

viewRender: function(view, element) {
    if (!CalLoading) {
        if (view.name == 'month') {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
        } else {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);
        }
    }
}

CalLoading = false;
```